# : Access violation writing location при изменении размера массива

Tags: c, массивы

Пишу программу, которая решает уравнение
Идея в том, что если я создаю массив относительно небольшого размера, то программа работает и все считает нормально, но как только я увеличиваю число элементов, вылазит исключение:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000000013FCD40D3 in vectorAdd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000001BF000.
```

Код следующий:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

const double length = 1;
const double _time = 1;

int numberOfNodesX;
int numberOfNodesT;

double *hostFunc;

__host__
double *initMatrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    return (double*)malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(double));
}

__device__ __host__
double left(double t)
{
    return 4;
}

__device__ __host__
double right(double t)
{
    return 2;
}

__host__
void setInitialAndBoundaryConditions(double* func, int rows, int columns, double h, double t)
{
    //func[0] = left(0); func[rows - 1] = right(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        func[i] = 0;
    }
}

__global__
void solveEquasion(double* func, int rows, int columns, double h, double t)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++)
    {

        if (index > 0 && index < rows - 1)
        {
            func[rows*i + index] = func[rows*(i - 1) + index] + t / (h*h)*
                (func[rows*(i - 1) + index + 1] - 2 * func[(i - 1)*rows + index] + func[(i - 1)*rows + index - 1]);

        }
        else if (index == rows - 1)
        {

            func[rows*i + index] = right(i*t);
        }
        else
        {
            func[rows*i] = left(i*t);
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

}

__host__
void saveToFile(double* func, int rows, int columns, const char* fileName)
{
    FILE * f = fopen(fileName, "w");
    for (int t = 0; t < columns; t++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            fprintf(f, "%f ", func[t*rows + x]);
        }
        fprintf(f, "\n");
    }
    fclose(f);

}



int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    clock_t start, end;
    double total_time;

    numberOfNodesX = 2048;

    double h = length / numberOfNodesX;
    double t = h * h / 2;

    numberOfNodesT = (int)(_time / t);

    hostFunc = initMatrix(numberOfNodesX, numberOfNodesT);
    if (hostFunc == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    setInitialAndBoundaryConditions(hostFunc, numberOfNodesX, numberOfNodesX, h, t);

    cudaError error = cudaSuccess;
    double *devFunc;

    error = cudaMalloc((void**)&devFunc, sizeof(double) * numberOfNodesX * numberOfNodesT);
    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Error!\nFailed to allocate memory on GPU!\n");
    }

    error = cudaMemcpy((void*)devFunc, (void*)hostFunc, numberOfNodesX*numberOfNodesT * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Error!\nFailed to cope memory from host to device!\n");
    }

    start = clock();

    solveEquasion << <1, numberOfNodesX >> > (devFunc, numberOfNodesX, numberOfNodesT, h, t);

    end = clock();

    total_time = ((double)(end - start));
    printf("Algorithm work time: %f\n", total_time);

    error = cudaMemcpy((void*)hostFunc, (void*)devFunc, sizeof(double)*numberOfNodesT*numberOfNodesX, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Error!\nFailed to copy memory from device to host!\n");
    }


    error = cudaFree((void*)devFunc);
    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Error!\nFailed to free memory on GPU!\n");
    }

    //saveToFile(hostFunc, numberOfNodesX, numberOfNodesT, "D:\\numbers.txt");

    free(hostFunc);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

К примеру, для сетки с количеством узлов по координате равным 1024 все работает, но для 2048 уже все валится. Количество временных слоев рассчитывается исходя из условия устойчивости явной разностной схемы уравнения теплопроводности.

Comment: Предположительно вы пишете мимо границ массива. Сложно что-то сказать без [минимального рабочего примера](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Что-то я подозреваю, что в этой куче перемножений где-то случается переполнение int

Comment: @HolyBlackCat поправил

Comment: @andreymal точно-точно, спасибо)